# Install Ubuntu on m.2 SSD independently

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have a dell 7559 with a 250GB SSD loaded with windows 10. I have another 275GB m.2 (Crucial) and I want to install Linux on it. Is it possible to install two OS in such a manner that they work completely independently without sharing any common space? That is, when I will use Linux it will show 275GB memory space (m.2) and when I will use Windows it will show 250GB memory space (original SSD). If yes then how should I proceed? Is such a separation better than dual boot with a common memory space in terms of performance?

Comment: You're talking about dual boot; whether the OS's are on different drives is irrelevant. And as far as I know, dual-booting can't impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

Dual booting is simple if you follow the right steps. 
Please follow the steps below:

- Boot into your `Windows` operating system.
- Search for `disk management` and select `Create and format hard disk partitions`
- Create a separate partition (unpartitioned space like say 100GB) where you will be installing Ubuntu
- Once all this is done, open the link [dual booting Ubuntu and Windows together](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) and follow the steps properly.
- Once Ubuntu gets installed on your system properly, then proceed with the next operation of setting up the grub menu. It will allow you to choose which OS you wish to boot into every time you start your system.

**Setting up Grub menu:**

- Simply boot into your `Windows` OS again
- Combine `Windows` + `r` keys together and type `cmd` to open command prompt.
- In command prompt window, type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and simply hit `Enter` key

Once all this is done, you will start getting Grub menu every time you boot your laptop.

Comment: Thank you @mAnN. My original concern is to install 2 OS without sharing a common memory space.

Comment: Bro the basic mean of `dual boot` is that you share the same hard disk and create multi partitions on it. Before I divulge further tell me - Is your 275 gb a separate hard disk? Is it inserted in your laptop, if yes then I am sure you will be able to see it in your Windows OS disk management window?

Comment: It is a separate SSD. Needs to be cloned with the original 250GB one as described here <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqF81fSg5qU>

Comment: Aah I see. Let me research and update you if its possible. If it can I will learn a new technique, and if its not possible you can repartition your Windows OS disk only...

Comment: Looking forward to your response bro

Comment: See if this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvIEuANr_1E`. or this link `https://www.linux.com/learn/clone-your-ubuntu-installation-new-hard-disk` helps you. Also, please note I am still against the idea of cloning, yet if you wish to try, cross check all aspects before initiating.